# Bypass php version check when installing extension

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using a community extension but it wont let me upload/install the extension. It says it supports 5.3 to 5.6.0 and I am running 5.6.23 so I figured its safe to install it on my system.

So question is, how can I bypass such checks?

Comment: It wont let me install the extension because of that.

Comment: Have you checked the code inside the extension? There should be a PHP check hardcoded in it

Comment: could be but i dont want to be editing extensions. its a third party extension

Answer (score 1):

(Unable to comment, so adding my thoughts as an answer)

Your best bet would be to contact the developer of the module and see if the module 1) will run on php 5.6.23 and 2) if so, can they update the module to allow it to install. In my experience, if it's a well maintained module, the developers tend to respond to such requests/questions in a reasonable time.

There very well could be a reason why it only supports up to 5.6.0 other than the module just not being updated. Even if you can figure out a way to bypass the check with or without modifying the code in the extension, it's possible other problems arise due to the version discrepancy.

Answer (score -1):

This is fixed.

There is a `--force` flag when you use mage cli.